# Может ли нейросеть стабильно сходиться на обучаемых значениях, и не сходиться на тестовых?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Я использую сети LSTM вместе с большим датасетом.

Датасет - большое количество временных измерений.
При этом loss, абсолютная ошибка и среднеквадратичная ошибка на обучаемых данных уменьшаются стабильно, с каждой эпохой, а на тестовых не уменьшаются вообще.

Т.е. речь не идет о переобучении. Такое вообще возможно (*с точки зрения логики работы, ведь датасет условно однороден, т.е. если нейронная сеть аппроксимирует обучающую выборку, должна аппроксимировать и тестовую*)?  При этом это не зависит от размера датасета - на разных длиннах обучающей/тестовой выборки ситуация повторяется

Или я где-то накосячил с получением обучающего и тестового набора?
Спасибо.

P.S. Визуально на графиках условная повторяемость прослеживается

Comment: Может быть что угодно, без предоставления воспроизводимого примера в виде данных и кода, сказать ничего невозможно. Но могу ванговать, что у вас наверное и правда какой-то косяк в подготовке данных.

Comment: @CrazyElf, при косяках, как правило, и не обучается. Да и рекомендации можно дать по описанному случаю, если, конечно, не самому всё делать (см. мой ответ).

Comment: @CrazyElf я не знаю, что приводить в качестве примера - у меня очень большой юпитер-блокнот, и большой датасет, не знаю, резонно ли его привести в пример

Comment: А само разделение на тренировочную и обучающую выборку как происходит? Может как-то перемешать данные перед разделением, иногда это помогает. А данные, кстати, не меняются со временем? А то и такое может быть, тогда к задаче нужно подходить как задаче на временные ряды, там и кросс-валидация другая тогда и вообще подходы несколько другие.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, это и есть задача на временные ряды. Разделение происходит так - беру 80% выборки - это обучающие данные, беру еще 20% - это тестовые данные

Comment: @venanen А, ну тогда понятно. С временными рядами нужно по особому работать, это вообще отдельная тема. Там нужно подбирать модель, которая на специальной валидации будет себя хорошо вести. Кросс-валидация для временных рядов выглядит так: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_cv_indices_013.png Последние две строки не смотрите, главное что выше.

Comment: @CrazyElf правильно ли я понимаю, что речь о том, что не просто разделить выборку, а с каждой эпохой наращивать размер обучающей выборки, а тестовую соответственно сдвигать вправо по времени? Если да, то интересно, изучу. Но насколько я понял из быстрого поиска - это позволяет подобрать гиперпараметры для сети (т.е. не учувствует в обучении)? Фактически я их подобрал руками (размер окна, например) - тем более, что мне даже не амплитуду предсказать нужно, а всего лишь больше или меньше измерение, чем ноль

Comment: @venanen Да, всё так. И это именно чтобы проверить, что модель нормально справляется с переменами в данных с течением времени. Что толку, если модель хорошо учит старые данные, но не может ничего показать на новых.

Comment: @CrazyElf прошу прощения, если не затруднит, нет ли у вас под рукой источника почитать про подобные решения? Потому как все, что я нахожу - примеры такого же рода, как сделал я  - просто сплит выборки на окна и обучение

Comment: Тема сложная и я её не очень хорошо знаю. Ищите именно "временные ряды" или на английском "time series". Там специфические термины и проверки. Тренд, стационарность, сезонность...

Answer (score 1):

Это все равно переобучение - сеть запоминает примеры, но не работает на тестах (=хорошее обучение и плохая работа с тестовыми последовательностями).

Три варианта, почему она переобучается (а в рекомендованном порядке применения):

1. Излишняя информационная емкость.
   а) Попробуйте уменьшить количество слоёв/нейронов.
   б) Попробуйте уменьшить последовательность до минимума.
2. Вообще не та архитектура (не та сеть выбрана - рекуррентная сеть хороша, но не на  все случаи жизни). Какая задача поставлена?
3. Неудачный датасет. Посмотрите методы предобработки и примените их.

По терминологии: "обучающие" примеры - не "обучаемые".

Comment: Увидел минус, да ещё и предложение на удаление. А нельзя комментарий получить к такой оценке с предложением? Ладно бы ещё встречный ответ был с противоположной идеей. А я уверен в рекомендациях.

Comment: @venanen, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - приниять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). И сообщите, в чём у вас было дело - интересно. Или напишите, если совсем не помогло по какой-то причине.

Comment: пока не тестировал. Сеть выбрана точно верно - для временных последовательностей их не так много - LSTM и GRU. У меня LSTM, архитектура - 2 слоя LSTM, слой Dropout, слой Dense с выходом. Датасет я вроде как подготовил, он стационарен, но с выбросами, которые нельзя убрать, т.к. это испортит последовательность, они важны. Другого датасета нет, единственный вариант - уменьшить кол-во слоев и нейронов, буду пробовать, спасибо. Плюс поставил

Comment: Непонятно, почему закрыт вопрос с комментарием "не по теме". Но чем дело-то у вас кончилось?

Comment: извиняюсь, что не ответил. Кто-то переоткрыл вопрос, только сейчас увидел. Я еще изучал тему - спустя еще часов 100 видео могу сказать - моя задача нерешаема, т.к. алгоритмически верное предсказание (с наименьшей ошибкой) - это просто последнее, поданное на вход. Т.е. график красивый, идеально повторяет входной, но смещен на одно измерение вправо. Нужно дополнительную информацию собирать

Comment: Несколько сомневаюсь в "нерешаемости". Сеть может себя так вести и это будет хорошо, но при этом loss, абсолютная ошибка и среднеквадратичная ошибка должны уменьшаться. Вы могли ошибиться с логикой обучения (например, обучали предсказывать на одно количество шагов, а в тестовой последовательности оно другое). Кроме того, кажется,  вы не стали уменьшать слои и нейроны. Ладно, давайте остановимся на этом, Успеха в познании нейросетей!